# How to integrate grails 3.0.5 project in GGTS 3.6.4

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

I am using grails-3.0.5 cause of i want to use groovy 2.4.4.

I created project by command

```
  >grails create-app Student
  >grails clean
```

Fine its working and created project.

But when i executed below command then command is there.

```
  >grails integrate-with --eclipse
```

Can anyone help me how to integrate with eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use eclipse and don't know what kind of integration do you mean, but `grails 3` is using `gradle` as a build tool and eclipse plugin is added automatically to the `build.gradle` file. You can execute `./gradlew eclipse` (or on windows `gradlew.bat eclipse`) to generate all eclipse related files.
To clean eclipse files you can use: `./gradlew cleanEclipse`.